# Redis connection issue with Redis

Tags: laravel-5, redis

I am trying to use Redis with Laravel5.4,I have installed redis using this command.

```
 composer require predis/predis

 // here is redis installed version.

 Redis server v=3.2.8 sha=00000000:0 malloc=libc bits=64
 build=50fbaa7e4990d389
```

But when i try to run "redis-cli",i get this error

> Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: show ps aux | grep redis if u on *nix

Comment: This show the same error,i am on mac and not using homestad